# How to find words or substring using positions in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have start and end index of words in Database now on page load I have to find the words using positions in javascript.

So how can we find words or substring using positions in javascript? I am using the below code to find positions.

```
function getSelectionCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
  var start = 0;
  var end = 0;
  var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
  var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
  var sel;
  if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {
    sel = win.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
      var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      var newNode = document.createElement("span");
      newNode.setAttribute("style", "background-color: yellow;");
      newNode.setAttribute('id', range);
      range.surroundContents(newNode);
      var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
      preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
      preCaretRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
      start = preCaretRange.toString().length;
      preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
      end = preCaretRange.toString().length;
    }
  } 
  else if ((sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
    var textRange = sel.createRange();
    var preCaretTextRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
    preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
    preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", textRange);
    start = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
    preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
    end = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
  }
  return {start: start, end: end};
}
```

Let say

`var str = "Hello how are you Hello how it is going"` is input and user select first Hello then index will be 0,4 and I save them in database next time on page load I want this "Hello" using 0,4 positions.

---

**Update: 1**

Now I am using this code but not it's working properly.

```
var abc = str.substring(a,b);

    replace(a, b, "<span style='background-color:yellow;'>" + abc + "</span>");

    function replace(first, last, replaceWith){
      maindata = maindata.substr(0, first) + 
              replaceWith +
              maindata.substr(last +1, maindata.length - last);
      // console.log(maindata);
      $('#detail_page').html(maindata);
```

It's skipping my text not highlighting all words. Please help

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is start index and end index of words?

Comment: if the user will select any word or substring then I am capturing indexes of that word or substring. So that is start and end index

Comment: I am not getting the exact word for which I have saved indexes. Its totally different.

Comment: Also include your desired output for a given input.

Comment: updated my question please check.

Comment: This is messy, maybe this can help: https://jsfiddle.net/7eut4dk8/1/

Comment: Okay, Thank Leave it. Can you help me I am using replace but it replaces always the first occurrence for the same characters. So what should i use in place of replace?

Comment: what i understood from you is this correct me if im wrong. you have an imput string like "hi man hi boy" you store the positions for example for hi it would be 0,1 and 7,8. for future you want to select these words based on some event like a search or something. am I correct?

Comment: yes Andam you are right i have to find words in exact those positions and then apply replace them with span tag for highlight purpose

Comment: @Andam  main thing is how it will distinguish which "hi" should be replaced with span tag as replace always work on first occurence.

Comment: Leave javascript alone how can you tell which hi you want to replace? based on postion?

Comment: yes, Andam that's the issue. How it will find which hi it will replace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr
the idea is to get from the start of the string (0) to the first letter of your word then get the second part of the string starting from last index of you word and put your span in between these two parts

for example if you have a string like "hello hi name" and you want to replace hi with span then you would say `mystring.substr(0, 6) + "span" + mystring.substr(8, 5)`

> note that substr takes start index and length that is why its 8, 5 in the above example

The code below does that. it will replace the text you want based on cordinates not first word. It will replace 2nd `hi` with `Name`

```js
var data = "hi hello hi hola";
var postitions = [{first: 0, last: 1}, {first: 9, last: 10}]

function replace(first, last, replaceWith){
  data = data.substr(0, first) + 
          replaceWith +
          data.substr(last +1, data.length - last);
  console.log(data)
}

replace(postitions[1].first, postitions[1].last, "Name")
```

Comment: Okay so it will replace words at specific positions right?

Comment: @Ankit I have explained in the answer now its updated

Comment: Hii @Andam  could you please modify according to my Below code.//  let text = document.getElementById("detail_page");

   //  $.each(words,function(key,value){

   //  let  innerHTML = text.innerHTML;

   //  innerHTML = innerHTML.replace(value,"<span style='background-color:yellow;'>" + value + "</span>");

   //  text.innerHTML = innerHTML;

Comment: I am not getting how I will use this thing in the loop. I have indexes in an array.

Comment: Hey @Andam i have updated my question please check once what i am doing wrong in that.

Comment: I dont understand you. It might be a language barrier. Sorry that is all i can do for you